# What is the correct way to create exception with NestJS and class-validator?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm using `class-validator` and `NestJS` and I'm facing the following situation: essentially I have defined a `Dto` file which have the following structure:

```
import {
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsEmail,
  IsDate,
  MaxDate,
  MinLength,
  MaxLength,
  Matches,
  IsString,
} from 'class-validator'
import { Type } from 'class-transformer'

export class CreateUserDto {
  @MinLength(5)
  @MaxLength(10)
  username: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string

  @IsString()
  @MinLength(4)
  @MaxLength(20)
  @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, {
    message: 'password too weak',
  })
  password: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsDate()
  @Type(() => Date)
  @MaxDate(require('moment')().subtract(13, 'y').toDate())
  dateOfBirth: Date

  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  lastName: string
}
```

so when I call `auth/register`, the `class-validator` automatically check `POST` and validate all fields, and in case of exception it returns:

```
{
    error: 'Bad Request',
    message: ['password too weak']
    statusCode: 400
}
```

that's good, but if I generate a custom exception using `NestJS`:

```
let exists = await this.userService.findByEmail(createUserDto.email)
if (exists) throw new ConflictException('email already exists')
```

I get:

```
{
    error: 'Bad Request',
    message: 'email already exists'
    statusCode: 400
}
```

As you can see `message` is not an array, and this lack of consistency. To fix this situation I have to surround the message with `['email already exists']`.

Is this a good approach or am I overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 0):

Class-valditor returns an array of errors if there are any errors, which is why you get this difference in message. You could create a filter to change the array of errors to a newline delimited string or similar, or you could just keep them both as is, or you can pass an array of strings to the error constructor. All are valid and fine approaches

Comment: Could you show me how to create a global filter which add also unhandled exception like 500 in an array automatically? Thanks

Comment: @sfarzoso Follow this https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1. Since the class-validator throws a BadRequest Exception you can simply pass it inside @Catch(BadRequestException) and catch it and then send the response the way you want it.